# Predicate Logic - Why is this not sufficient?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let N be the set on Natural numbers. Let S={2,6,14} and T={6,8,11}.

**Question:** The intersection of S and T is nonempty

The correct answer is this:

> $∃ x : x ∈ S. ∃ y : y ∈ T. x=y$

My answer is this:

> $∃ x : x ∈ S  ∧ x ∈ T$

Is my answer a sufficient way of saying `the value x is in the intersection of S and T`?

If not, why does the correct answer refer to two variables, x and y? Can x only represent the values in one set, even when they intersect?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Note that the "correct" answer only quantifies over defined sets, whereas your answer quantifies over the entire universe.  Depending on your text, unrestricted quantification may not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct ... if you add some parentheses:

$\exists x (x \in S \land x \in T)$

This is logically equivalent to the provided answer, and so no, you don't need a different variable just because you have different sets; it is the *same* object that is in the intersection, so you can indeed do exactly what you do.

Finally, your statement is not quite saying 'x is the intersection of S and T' (because for different S and T they may have more than 1 element in common), but it is saying that 'x is *in* the intersection of S and T', and hence that the intersection is not empty.

Comment: is there any reason to refer to 2 variables and 2 quantifiers instead of one?

Comment: Your version and the OP's version are just the same thing written in different syntax.

Comment: The provided answer doesn't use parentheses either. Notations vary, and it is correct for Francis to use the same notation that the instructor is using, and not some different notation.

Comment: I thnk the provided answer has no parenthesis since it requires no parentheses. Think of it as $\exists x \in S \: \exists y \in T x = y$. Some syntactical notations are fine with that.  But I have not seen any notation that is fine with $\exists x x \in S \land x \in T$

Comment: @Francis No, you don't need two variables just because you are dealing with two sets. Just added that to my answer.